# How can I set page background color using ResoureDictionary?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I created a `ResourceDictionary` file to store a `Page`'s background color. Next, I referenced that `ResourceDictionary` in my main page.

While the Visual Studio 2019 (16.7.7) designer correctly renders the `Page`'s background color in red, the running program itself doesn't.

[image: Visual Studio 2019 - UWP]

What am I doing wrong?

---

### Here are the sources:

#### MainPage.xaml

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="Test1.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock>
            Test
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

#### Dictionary1.xaml

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">

    <Style TargetType="Page">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Jim Walker @ https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/2790#issuecomment-722065687 :

> the preferred way to change colors in your app is [*lightweight styling*](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/xaml-styles#lightweight-styling), which is overriding the system brushes that controls use by creating your own brush with the same key. The class documentation for most controls has a list of resources that you can override.
>
> For the `Page` background, you override the `ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush` resource:
>
> ```xml
> <Application.Resources>
>     <ResourceDictionary>
>         <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
>             <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
>                 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Red"/>
>                 <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
>                     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
>                 </Style>
>             </ResourceDictionary>
>         </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
>     </ResourceDictionary>
> </Application.Resources>
> ```
>
> (Since it's a [ThemeResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/themeresource-markup-extension), it needs to be in a theme dictionary. I'm using a dictionary with the key "Default" to keep it simple, but it's better to use both "Light" and "Dark" resources as discussed in [XAML theme resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources).)
>
> This also assumes that the page background is set to this resource, which it is by default in Visual Studio templates, like this: `Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing the resource dictionary in the `Page` you want to import this resource dictionary in your `App.xaml` like so:

```xml
<Application
    x:Class="Test1.App">
    
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then you'll need to add a `x:Key` to your custom style:

```xml
<Style x:Key="CustomPageBackground" TargetType="Page">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

Now in your `Page` you only need to add the following line:

```xml
Style="{StaticResource CustomPageBackground}"
```

Like so:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="Test1.MainPage"
    Style="{StaticResource CustomPageBackground}"
    ...>
    
    <!-- UI-elements -->
</Page>
```

Comment: Thanks, @leander, for providing me with this solution! I'm asking this question particularly to get a deeper understanding for the framework. So, from your solution, you're implying that a `ResourceDictionary` can *not* be applied to its *own* object but only to *children* of that object? (Inheritance not considered, like you did.)

Comment: I'm asking this because I think I may have found a bug in UWP. Because the following doesn't work, either, though it should: `<Page>
 <Page.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="Page">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Lavender" />
  </Style>
 </Page.Resources>
</Page>`

Comment: @AxD No it doesn't, you are just defining the style and not setting the style of the page to this style. You should either use `<Page><Page.Style><Style TargetType="Page"><Setter Property="Background Value="Lavender"/></Style></Page.Style></Page>`, or define style in somewhere higher in the hierarchy.

Comment: If that's the case, then documentation must be wrong. Throughout that page they're using the code I'm using: https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/xaml-styles

Comment: hm yeah forgot about implicit styles, havent used it for a while... Did you try setting for example a `Button.Resources` to change its style? Wondering whether this works.

Comment: Thanks, Leander. Good question. Actually, that's [another query I raised at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64637614/why-are-resources-not-used-in-this-page/64639956) yesterday.