# Why are resources not used in this page?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

No matter where I put my resources, their value isn't used:

[image]

The `TextBlock` text should be rendered black, but it's always rendered white.

Why?

---

#### Here is the source:

```xml
<Page
  x:Class="TemplateTest.MainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d" Background="Lavender">

  <Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    </Style>
  </Page.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
    <ListView>
      <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock>
            <Run>Test</Run>
            <Run>!</Run>
          </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.HeaderTemplate>

      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
          <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>

      <x:String>Number 1</x:String>
      <x:String>Number 2</x:String>
      <x:String>Number 3</x:String>
    </ListView>
  </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Jim Walker @ https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/2790#issuecomment-722065687 :

> `TextBlock` is different from most controls in that it doesn't have an editable template, so, unfortunately, it doesn't support lightweight styling. You have to use a `Style` to set the foreground. And, as we already know, a Page- or App-level implicit style won't be applied to `TextBlock`s inside a `DataTemplate`, so you have to use a separate implicit `Style` inside the `DataTemplate` or a `Style` with a key to change those `TextBlock`s . As far as I know, there isn't any way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Use x:key and provide a name to it and then refrence that name using staticresource in textblock:

```
<Page
  x:Class="TemplateTest.MainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d" Background="Lavender">

    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="tbstyle">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <ListView>
          <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Style={StaticResources tbstyle}>
                <Run>Test</Run>
                <Run>!</Run>
              </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.HeaderTemplate>

          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
              <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}" Style={StaticResources tbstyle}></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>

          <x:String>Number 1</x:String>
          <x:String>Number 2</x:String>
          <x:String>Number 3</x:String>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```